# Expected value of index of an n-digit number found in pi

Tags: expected-value, pi, decimal-expansion

Let $E(n)$ be the expected value of the index of finding an n-digit number in the digits of pi

e.g.

- Number 0 is found at index 32
- Number 1 is found at index 1
- Number 2 is found at index 6
- Number 3 is found at index 9
- Number 4 is found at index 2
- Number 5 is found at index 4
- Number 6 is found at index 7
- Number 7 is found at index 13
- Number 8 is found at index 11
- Number 9 is found at index 5

$$E(1) = 90/10 = 9$$

I could probably compute $E(2)$ and $E(3)$ using a computer program.

What is an equation for $E(n)$? If too hard, what would be a good lower and upper bound for it? Has any work ever been done on this topic?

Comment: It's not even known that each digit occurs infinitely often...thus it may be the case that $E(n)$ is undefined for large $n$ .  In any case, not much is known about such things.  Standard conjectures give you some view on the distributions here, but they are only conjectures.

Comment: Let $E_x(n)$ be the generalisation obtained by asking the same question about a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) $x$ instead of $\pi$. The average of $E_x(n)$ over all normal $x\in(0,\,1)$ would be a tractable variant of your question. Would it interest you?